# GPU computing for bootstrapping using "boot" package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gpu, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to do a large analysis using bootstrapping. I saw that the speed of bootstrapping is increased using parallel computing as in the following code:

**Parallel computing**

```
# detect number of cpu
library(parallel)
detectCores()

library(boot)
# boot function --> mean
bt.mean <- function(dat, d){
  x <- dat[d]
  m <- mean(x)
  return(m)
}

# obtain confidence intervals
# use parallel computing with 4 cpus
x  <- mtcars$mpg
bt <- boot(x, bt.mean, R = 1000, parallel = "snow", ncpus = 4)
quantile(bt$t, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
```

However, as the whole number of calculations is large in my case (10^6 regressions with 10,000 bootstrap samples), I read that there are ways to use GPU computing to increase the speed even more ([link1](http://www.parallelr.com/blog/), [link2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html)). You can easily use GPU computing with some functions like in:

**GPU computing**

```
m   <- matrix(rnorm(10^6), ncol = 1000)
csm <- gpuR::colSums(m)
```

But it seems to me that the packages can only handle some specific R functions such as matrix operations, linear algebra or cluster analysis ([link3](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing)).
Another approach is to use CUDA/C/C++/Fortran to create own functions ([link4](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/)). But I am rather searching for a solution in R.

My question is therefore:

Is it possible to use GPU computing for bootstrapping using the `boot` package and other R packages (e.g. `quantreg`)?

Comment: When I go to the second link and search on "boot" I get multiple hits?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are right but only one section of this Task View deals with GPU computing (not CPU). The rest is just on parallel computation - or did you find something I didn't?

Comment: If you pass an object for which there is a gpu-aware method such as gpuR::colMeans then ordinary function dispatch should take care of this. The interfaces to gpu's tends to be fairly OS- specific and you have not indicated what sort of hardware and software might be the targets for this effort.

Comment: Thanks again 42! I have the options to use Linux or Windows operating systems and I have access to CUDA GPU. But I was rather thinking if there is a feasible approach that is not OS and hardware-specific - just as in your example "gpuR::colMeans". Another [website](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/) explains an approach to use C/C++/Fortran to connect R and CUDA but I am rather searching for a solution using only R if that is possible...

Comment: If you don't find an existing approach, another option might be to negotiate to have someone build out the functionality you need as a new package or an extension to an existing one. That would probably involve C/C++/Fortran development with an R wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to gain the power of gpu computing freely without doing any additional programming now. But the gpuR package is a good starting point. As you point out, the gpuR can only handle some specific R functions such as matrix operations and linear algebra, it is restricted but useful, for example, linear regression can be easily formulated to a linear algebra problem. As to quantile regression, it is not that straightforward to translate it to a linear algebra as linear regression, but it can be done. For example, you can use Newton-Raphson algorithm or something other numerical optimization algorithm to deal with quantile regression (it is not that hard as it sounds like), and the Newton algorithm is in linear algebra form.

The gpuR package is already hiding a lot of c++ programming details and hardware details to utilize gpu computing power and provides a quite easy-to-use programming style, as long as I can think of, this is the way to achieve what you want with the least effort: to rely on the gpuR package, formulate your problem in matrix operations and linear algebra (Newton Raphson etc) and do the programming yourself, or maybe you can find some Newton Raphson implementation in R for quantile regression, and make some little modifications necessary, for example, use gpuMatrix instead of matrix, etc. Hope it helps.