# Is possible to use GPU parallel computing in R for uniroot (or equivalent)?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gpu, solver, mapply

I am trying to speedup the following code in R, which is calling `uniroot` on 1000 different cases using `mapply` (one for each equation form with each element of the vectors a, ce and w -- see below).

In order to run this code faster, I would like to use my GPU (a NVIDIA card) in order to parallelize the computation. Here is a simple example (of the actual computation):

```
a  = exp(seq(log(1), log(401), length.out = 1000)) - 1
ce = runif(1000, min = 0.9, max = 4)
w  = runif(1000, min = 0.9, max = 4)

fun1 = function(ce, w, a) {
  return(uniroot(function(h) ce * 0.32 * (1 - h)^-0.35  - 0.8 * ((0.0093 + 0.01) / 0.33)^(0.33 / (0.33 - 1))*(1 - 0.04) * (w * h + 0.0093 * a)^-0.16, c(0.5, 0.99999), extendInt = "yes")$root)
}

out = mapply(fun1, ce = ce, w = w, a = a)
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43887664/gpu-computing-for-bootstrapping-using-boot-package) that you can use Newton-Raphson algorithm with GPU, but I don't get how to do it. Can someone give me a hint (or a working example) on how to parallelize this?

Thank you in advance!

Note: I call this mapply function lots of time, so the actual time used by it is considerably.

Comment: While not for a GPU, you can try ```library(future.apply); plan(multiprocess); future_mapply(...)```. On my 2-core machine, I don't see any improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I could that, but what I am looking for is to parallelize using the GPU. If I understand correctly, the future framework is for parallel computing using the CPU cores, not the GPU :(